# Javascript chained relational operators supported?

Tags: javascript

I just played around with some JS core principles and found, that the engine evaluates chained relational operators without throwing an error. Instead they are evaluated in a way I can't understand for myself.

```
console.log(1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5); //true, expected
console.log(5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1); //false, should be true
console.log(5 >= 4 >= 3);       //false, should be true
console.log(7 >= -2 >= 1);      //true, should be false
console.log(1 <= -2 <= 7);      //true, should be false
```

Is this even officially supported? I also found no mentions in literature / documentations on this and I am rather confused why this is even working.

Somebody can light this up a bit?

Comment: `3 > 2 > 1 === true > 1 === false`.

Comment: `1 < 2 < 3 < 4 < 5`  Evaluate left to right.  1 is less than 2.  true.  true is less than 3, so true.  true is also less than 4, so true.  true is also less than 5.  so true.  follow the same reasoning for the rest.

Comment: See: https://es5.github.io/#x11.8 (or later specifications)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They're binary operators, with left associativity. They're parsed as

```
console.log((((1 < 2) < 3) < 4) < 5); // true (true < 5)
console.log((((5 > 4) > 3) > 2) > 1); // false (true > 1)
console.log((5 >= 4) >= 3);           // false (true >= 3)
console.log((7 >= -2) >= 1);          // true (true >= 1)
console.log((1 <= -2) <= 7);          // true (false <= 7)
```

and will compare boolean partial results with numbers.

Answer (score 3):

`1 < 2` evaluates to `true`

`true < 3` evaluates to `true`

`true < 4` evaluates to `true`

`true < 5` evaluates to `true`

---

`5 > 4` evaluates to `true`

`true > 3` evaluates to `false`

`false > 2` evaluates to `false`

`false > 1` evaluates to `false`

---

The reason for this logic is that `true` and `false` are treated as `1` and `0` respectively for these sorts of comparisons.